# AWS Cloudformation Cross stack ref for Security group - error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have below 2 stacks
1) Stack 1 - this is network stack, defines vpc, subnets and security group
2) Stack 2 - this stack defines ec2 instance

Network stack exports following

```
   WebServerSG:
     Description : "Web Server Security Group"
     Value: !GetAtt InstanceSecurityGroup.GroupId
     Export:
       Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-WebServerSG
```

The ec2 instance stack accepts a parameter "NetworkStack" and uses the network stack to refer to the security group as follows

```
  "Resources" : {
    "WebServerInstance": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "ImageId" : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSRegionArch2AMI", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },
                          { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSInstanceType2Arch", { "Ref" : "InstanceType" }, "Arch" ] } ] },
        "InstanceType"   : { "Ref" : "InstanceType" },
        "SubnetId" : {"Fn::ImportValue" : {"Fn::Sub" : "${NetworkStack}-SubnetADMZ"}},
        "SecurityGroupIds" : {"Fn::ImportValue" : {"Fn::Sub" : "${NetworkStack}-WebServerSG"}},
        "KeyName"  : { "Ref" : "KeyName" }
        }
    }
  },
```

The ec2 instance stack fails with the error , "Value of property SecurityGroupIds must be of type List of String"

I tried to use SecurityGroups instead , but received similar error

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: @tambre I think "Infrastructure as Code (IaC)" tools like CloudFormation are an exception. It clearly blurs the line between traditional IT (Serverfault) and programming (StackOverflow). One thing is certain, the "amazon-cloudformation" tag has way more activity here (2239 questions), than on Serverfault (180 questions).

Comment: @LaurentJalbertSimard JSON and YAML aren't programming languages though? To me CloudFormation template/stack files seem like just very capable configuration file formats.

Comment: @tambre I think the rise of DevOps makes the line even more blurred. The idea behind having separate Stack Exchange sites is that it's easier to focus one topics regarding your line of work. StackOverflow -> Developper, Serverfault -> System Operator/Administrator. But with DevOps you handle dev and ops. These are no longer separate topics, especially when the question is related to IaC. I'm not saying that you're wrong, but I believe that the issue is more complex than you think.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you want to specify only 1 security group, CloudFormation wants a list. The solution here is to make a list of one element, the element being the imported security group. In your case it will look like this (notice the brackets):

```
...
"SecurityGroupIds" : [{"Fn::ImportValue" : {"Fn::Sub" : "${NetworkStack}-WebServerSG"}}],
...
```

Comment: I am running into the same issue, and trying to implement the above solution  in yaml , but does not work . My assumption is that the characters "[" and "]" in yaml needs to be appended using Fn::Join with the security group.   .                                                                                                     SecurityGroupIds: 
   Fn::Join:
               - ''
               -  - '['
               - Fn::ImportValue:
                 !Sub ${SGStack}-WebSg
               - ']'

Answer (score 0):

Laurent Jalbert Simard answer is correct. Fn:ImportValue should be enclosed in [] to provide imported value as list.